# How to boost a QueryParser in Lucene-6?

Tags: java, lucene

In `lucene` v5 it was possible to boost a query as follows:

```
Query q = new QueryParser("param", paramAnalyzer).parse(param);
q.setBoost(10f);
```

But in v6 there is no `setBoost()` method anymore.

**Question**: how can I still boost in v6?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of 6.0, you will need to wrap the query in a [`BoostQuery`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/6_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/BoostQuery.html), instead.  Like this:

```
Query q = new QueryParser("param", paramAnalyzer).parse(param);
q = new BoostQuery(q, 10f);
```

See also: [LUCENE-6590](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-6590)

Comment: For future users: beware there is also a `BoostedQuery` class, which should not be used here.